# How do I make it so that variable Increments every one second in the background

Tags: java, increment, clock

My problem is that I need a clock to be included in my code.  The problem is, is I don't know how to have I increment every second without entirely pausing the whole code.  Can someone tell me a better way of doing it or can someone tell me how many time a second a variable can increase in java so I can just use the % to calculate how many times the clock needs to increment.

Code:

```
int miniseconds = 0;
    int seconds = 00;
    int minutes = 00;
    int hours = 00;
    int day = 1;
    int month = 1;
    int years = 2280;
    int yearLeap = years % 4;
    long i;
    for (i = 1000000000; i>0; i--){
    seconds ++;
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);//2000ms = 2s
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    }
    if (seconds == 60){
        minutes ++;
        seconds =0;
    }

    if (minutes == 60){
        hours++;
        minutes = 0;
    }
    if (hours == 24){
        day++;
        hours = 0;
    }
    if (month == 1 && day == 32 ){
        month ++;
        day = 1;

    }
    if (month == 2 && day == 30 && yearLeap == 0) {
        month ++;
        day = 1;
    }
    if (month == 2 && day == 29 && yearLeap != 0){
        month ++;
        day = 1;
    }
    if (month == 3 && day == 32){
        month ++;
        day = 1;
    }
    if (month == 4 && day == 31){
        month ++;
        day = 0;
    }
    if (month == 5 && day == 32){
        month ++;
        day = 0;
    }
    if (month == 13){
        month = 1;
            years ++;
    }
    String date = "The current time is:  " +day+ "/" +month+ "/" +years+ "  " +hours+ ":" +minutes+ ":" +seconds;
    }
```

Comment: This is where a Javax.Swing.Timer class would be of benefit http://www.asjava.com/swing/java-timer-tutorial/

Comment: or `ScheduledExecutorService`

Comment: While a `ScheduledExecutorService` would do this, have you considered just using a `java.time.Clock`?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the following example for Java Timers at this address: http://www.asjava.com/swing/java-timer-tutorial/

The example assumes that you are using the Java.Swing libraries and that you require a UI for your application rather than using the console.

---

**ClockLabel.java**

```
// An extension of the JLabel class that listens to events from a Timer object to
// update itself with the current date & time.
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {
  public ClockLabel( ) {
    super("" + new Date( ));
    Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
    t.start( );
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    setText((new Date( )).toString( ));
  }
}
```

---

**ClockTest.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ClockTest extends JFrame {
  public ClockTest( ) {
    super("Timer Demo");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ClockLabel clock = new ClockLabel( );
    getContentPane( ).add(clock, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ClockTest ct = new ClockTest( );
    ct.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Acceptable answer if you're already using Swing. *Do not* use Swing just for a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is some sort of homework because otherwise you could of course use the internal clock.

You need to put that updating logic into a new Thread which runs parallel. Write a runnable ([This should get you started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)) and include a loop there (probably `while(true)`) which does the updating.

Answer (score 0):

This will call a suitable method every second:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
      Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Runnable task = () -> myObj.incrementSeconds();
final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, SECONDS);
```

Note that there are issue with multithreaded access to variables, so you should make sure you understand topics like atomicity, the `volatile` keyword etc. before relying on variables shared between multiple threads. There are many books about Java concurrency.

However, you seem to be writing a clock class. There is already `java.time.Clock` which is very flexible and reliable.